# The best way to extend fsproj template

Tags: f#, project, vs-extensibility

I want to create custom project template based on F# project (fsproj). Requirements:

- Custom project properties. So, property page extension required.
- Custom file type support. Custom project item template should be created.
- Custom build action for custom file type. Corresponded MsBuild task will be created.

As I know, some parts of C# project ecosystem are in SDK, so can be inherited (it looks useful for deep customization), but F# is not. So my question is what the best way for deep customization of F# project template?